# Meaning of まん in ほっとかれちゃたまんない

Tags: grammar, meaning, contractions

> あんなところにいつまでもほっとかれちゃた**まん**ない

I can't understand what まん means in this sentence. Literally I'm reading

> There is no まん that got neglected forever in such a place.

which is gibberish.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

「まん」 there is not a word.

> 「たま**ん**ない」＝「たま**ら**ない」 = "unbearable", "unendurable"

just like

「わか**ん**ない」＝「わか**ら**ない」= "I don't know." or "I don't understand."

「つま**ん**ない」＝「つま**ら**ない」= "boring" or "(I'm) bored."

In colloquial speech (around the larger Kanto region), 「ら」***often*** becomes 「ん」.

> 「あんなところにいつまでもほっとかれちゃたまんない。」
>
> = "It's unbearable to be left alone in a place like that for so long!"

Comment: I'm glad I looked at your edit history because I was also wondering about precisely the thing that you deleted :)