# Explanation of どうにもなんない

Tags: grammar

Could you explain to me how どうにもなんない works ?

I know that どうにも  + V + ない = not by any means, but here I have なん in between instead of a verb.

Context: a boy has just died and is being discouraged to move on to the after life.

> もちろん死んだんだから、えっちいことだってできないし、そもそも体がないんだから**どうにもなんない**わね

My try:

> Since you are dead, you can't even hook up with anyone ! Since you
> don't have a body, there is nothing you can do

**edit:**

as – istrasci suggested, is is どうにもなんない = どうにもな**ら**ない　？？

I believed before it was どうにもな**に**ない ？

Comment: Does this help?  https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/41478/78

Comment: thanks for the pointer, I'm still not sure. Anyways, I have updated the question

Comment: @istrasci is correct, it does mean どうにもならない. And your translation is correct too. It is (to me) a very Japanese idiom that does not have an exact equivalent in english, but it more or less "it will not become anything" (no matter what you try, you will not achieve anything). 

Note that while your general understanding of どうにも + V + ない is correct, I cannot help but wonder if どうにもならない is a special case derived from [どうもこうもならない](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%81%A9%E3%81%86%E3%82%82%E3%81%93%E3%81%86%E3%82%82). I may be completely wrong, but in any case it is an interesting old tale!

Comment: It's right - ならない is contracted in casual speech to なんない

Answer (score 4, accepted):

どうにもなんない is a contracted form of どうにもならない, which means "there is no way", "it amounts to nothing", "hopeless", "to end up being meaningless" etc., depending on the context.

This contraction pattern is described in general here: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/61959/5010

So "na**ran**ai" becomes "na**n-n**ai".